# React Native FTP library isn't install

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, expo, ftp

"https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ftp". When I run the library in the link with the command
`npm install react-native-ftp --save`
it gives the following error.

`npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree npm ERR! npm ERR! While resolving: trial@1.0.0 npm ERR! Found: react-native@0.72.3 npm ERR! node_modules/react-native npm ERR! react-native@"0.72.3" from the root project npm ERR! npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency: npm ERR! peer react-native@"^0.41.2" from react-native-ftp@1.0.1 npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-ftp npm ERR! react-native-ftp@"*" from the root project npm ERR! npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution. npm ERR! npm ERR! npm ERR! For a full report see:`

I also run it with the command `npm install react-native-ftp --save --force`. I'm loading and importing the library but when I try to use the library in my project it acts like nothing is installed. So for example `FTP.setup("192.168.1.1",21);` When I type it, it gives an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect' of null`. Note: this library requires @0.41.2 of React Native. How can I solve this?

I tried other FTP libraries written for React Native but doesn't work none.There are some Javascript libraries but them doesn't work with React Native. if react-native-ftp library hasn't solution, how can I use Javascript libraries on ReactNative ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.